# Elixir Ecto update_all doesn't always work

Tags: elixir, ecto

We have an identities-users relationship where an identity can have many users. There is a method to link users to be tied to one identity using this code.

```
from(u in ZB.User, where: u.identity_id == ^to_link_identity.id)
|> ZB.Repo.update_all(set: [identity_id: user.identity_id])

ZB.Repo.delete(to_link_identity)
```

Sometimes (a majority of the time this works fine) this will throw an error because the foreign key on `to_link_identity` recognizes that there are still users connected to it, showing that the `update_all` didn't update all of the users to the new `identity_id`. From the docs (https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update_all/3) I don't see a way to catch an error. Is there a better way to handle this to avoid this error?

Comment: It is possible that you have a race condition where you update, insert a new record, then attempt to delete the record. Try throwing the update and delete here into a transaction and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: thanks I will give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Justin Wood's recommendation I came up this solution, which has appeared to fix the problem.

```
Ecto.Multi.new()
|> Ecto.Multi.update_all(:update, from(u in ZB.User, where: u.identity_id == ^to_link_identity.id), set: [identity_id: user.identity_id])
|> Ecto.Multi.delete(:delete, to_link_identity)
|> ZB.Repo.transaction
```